# dual boot with grub xubuntu / windowsxp, how to change the order from within XP?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, multi-boot, grub2

I have WindowsXP installed on one partition and i have installed Xubuntu on a second partition. It also installed grub so i can choose with OS to start.

The problem is that i am connected to the computer from remote connection using VNC. When the Xununtu is on and i want the XP, there is no problem. I just change the grub startup order using startupmanager to XP and i restart the computer, wait a few seconds and reconnect with VNC.

But now when i am in the XP, How can i change back to the Xubuntu?
Any other idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Which file system are you using in Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using ext4 - but i don't want to just read the linux partitions - i want to be able to reboot with linux again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount /boot with ext2tools or whatever and modify the boot order

Answer (score 2):

Would this do the trick?

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-read-ext3ext4-linux-partition-from-windows-7.html

It will also run under XP